# Installing VirtualBox in linux via a script with also includes signing kernal modules

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kernel

I have a linux VM (ubuntu 20.04) with secure boot settings active. Basically I need to install virtualBox and then create multiple VMs via virtual box via script only. No manual intervention should be required.

Since, it's secured boot these kernel modules needs to be signed: 1- vboxnetadp 2- vboxnetflt 3- vboxdrv

The instructions https://gist.github.com/dublado/d0321da690c633e7799d5d504e3b52c1 explains how to sign these kernel modules but it also asks to reboot the system and while rebooting, these steps has to be followed -
During the boot when prompted choose Enroll MOK
You will see the keys that were created and signed and choose Continue

How can I perform these steps from the script ? Is there any other way i can install virtual box (or other tool) for virtualization ?

Thanks you so much in advance!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try [this post](https://gist.github.com/reillysiemens/ac6bea1e6c7684d62f544bd79b2182a4). There doesn't seem to exist a method that does not require boot input.

Comment: Your question appears to need a script writing service.   From my point of view, this is off topic.